# Algorithm question. I don't understand sentence quoted. Please help me out

Tags: algorithm

Question from Programming Pearls, 2nd edition:

Given a sequential file containing 4,300,000,000 32-bit integers, how can you find one that appears at least twice?

Solution provided in the book:

> Binary search find an element that occurs at least twice by recursively searching the subinterval that contains more than half of the integers. My original solution did not guarantee that the number of integers is halved in each iteration, so the worst case run time of its *log<sub>2</sub> n* passes was proportional to *n·log n*.  Jim Saxe reduced that to linear time by observing that the search can avoid carrying too many duplicates.
>
> > When his search knows that a
> >     duplicate must be in a current range
> >     of *m* integers, it will only store *m+1*
> >     integers on its current work tape;
>
> If more integers would have gone on the tape, his program discards them.  Although his method frequently ignores input variables, its strategy is conservative enough to ensure that it finds at least one duplicate.

---

Above is content from the book.  I don't understand the sentences quoted.  How exactly can it be implemented?  I mean, how can he know that "a duplicate must be in the current range of *m* integers"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it refers to the pigeonhole principle, that if the difference between the minimum and the maximum element in a set is less than the cardinality of the set, there must be a duplicate.

And you can check this as you're building your subsets and stop building them as soon as you're certain a duplicate has to exist in that subset.

Comment: Um, what?  I still don't understand the question.  Are you guys working of something in the book that isn't stated in the question?

Comment: @Jason Goemaat The question is that if you have `n` numbers which can only have `k<n` distinct values, how do you find a duplicate? And in quicksort you recursively split your array into two parts. If, during your splitting you find that one of your parts already contains more elements then there are distinct values between its minimum and maximum elements (which you have to keep track of), you don't have to finish the split operation.

Comment: Nowhere does the question or answer mention quicksort...  Does that mean that you actually perform the quicksort?

Comment: @Jason Goemaat My mistake, forget about quicksort. I meant binary search, I don't know why I wrote quicksort.

Answer (score 3):

2 ^ 32 = 4,294,967,296. You have a file with 4,300,000,000 integers, guaranteeing duplicates.

1. Find the central number, it should 2^31 = 2147483648. If it is less, the duplicates are most probably in the second half. If not, duplicates have occurred in the first half.
2. Find the central number again, it should 2^30 = 1073741824...

Repeat until you find the duplicate.

Comment: That's if it the datatype is unsigned integer.

Comment: If they are signed, the central number would be 0 on the first attempt, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I think that book might be a bit old. This is a basic binary search problem.

And I think the book is kind of awkward. Maybe try wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: It isn't that basic, first of all, it relies on the fact that your elements are integers.